# Ruby - RoR. ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

for first sorry for my english.

I've a Rails app with a namespaced route that works fine on localhost
but does not work on remote Server.

This is my error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant
Monitor::PapTagsController):
```

My routes.rb

```
namespace :monitor do
    resources :pap_tags do
      resources :pap_tag_rules
    end
  end
```

file is: pap_tags_controller.rb

```
class PapTagsController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

It's very strange, can you help me?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between local and remote probably come from some file existing on your local copy but not on your remote one (maybe not checked into source control ?).

Also if you are using a namespaced controller you need to declare it as such :

```
class Monitor::PapTagsController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

and put this file in a `monitor` subdirectory inside `app/controllers`.